# joomla code debugging

Tags: joomla1.5

i m new to joomla 1.5...
i want to debug my joomla component independantly...
is their any tool to debug the joomla components 's code with current value like c and c++
watch

Answer (score 0):

FirePHP offers some php debugging capabilities. Furthermore here is a tutorial on using FirePHP to debug Joomla! code.

[FirePHP to debug Joomla! code](http://www.howtojoomla.net/how-tos/development/how-to-debug-your-joomla-code-with-firephp)